# Wrong animation after collada export

Tags: armature, export, bones, collada, dae

I have a problem with Blender when exporting my model to Collada.
I created a simple chest after following a tutorial on Youtube.

I order to animate the opening of the top-part, I've added a single bone and set the parent's object with an armature deform with empty groups.
After that, I selected the corresponding vertices of the bone's vertex groups and assigned them.

Finally, in pose mode, added the rotation & location keyframes.

The animation in Blender is what I wanted, but after exporting as a Collada file, my model seems to "turn" around an other axis (with the native viewer of MacOS at least...).
Despite checking different options, I wasn't able to find where the problem is.

[image: Animation in Blender] On Blender
[image: Collada model] Collada model

Could you help me figuring what the problem is ? Thanks !

[image]

EDIT : If "Use Blender Profile" wasn't checked before the collada export, when I try to import the file again in Blender I get this :

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be exported as a .dae? Have you tried an .fbx export?

Comment: Yes, for some reason I really need to export in dae format (I'm loading it in C++, and the collada loader is fully implemented). I saw that there was the possibility of exporting to fbx and then dae through Cheetah3D. But considering the price of the tool, meh...

Comment: I exported it as a usdc and it worked fine. However exporting it as a dae didn't work, like you said.

Comment: It's always a good practice if you have a root bone, parent of all bones which never moves.

Comment: I just added a fixed root bone. After the export, the main box doesn't move but the lid of the chest continues to move oddly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, here's my steps if someone get stuck with the same problem.

Just before exporting the model to .dae, in Pose mode, I had to select the bones (I've added a static root bone since my first post) and reset the rotation, translation and scale by pressing respectively Option+R, Option+T and Option+S (ALT+R, ALT+T, ALT+S on Windows).

After that, in Object Mode, I selected the mesh, and applied all the transforms ("Object" menu > Apply > All Transforms). Did the same with the armature.

After the export, everything seems to be ok !

Answer (score 0):

I don't whether this helps your in your case, but if i export to .dae with

[image]

...export to SL checked

and

[image]

transform : decomposed, i could successfully import it to Blender again and the animation worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem here as I can import my previous dae file into blender with the correct animations. It's when viewing it in the macos viewer that it doesn't work (same result after loading it in c++).
In addition, with your solution, nothing is displayed in the macos viewer :/

Comment: EDIT: "Nothing is displayed": in fact there's the model but I had to rotate the viewer. In both cases, I can import the files in blender only if "Use Blender Profile" was checked before exporting.